# File inheriting permission of directory it is copied in?

Tags: linux, files, permissions, cp, file-copy

I have files created into my home directory with only user read permission (`r-- --- ---`). I want to copy this file to another directory `/etc/test/` which has the folder permission of 744 (`rwx r-- r--`). I need to allow for the file I am copying to inherit the permission of the folder it is copied in because so far when I copy it, the files permissions are still the same (`r-- --- ---`). I have tried setfacl command, but it did not work? Please help.

PS. I can't just `chmod -r /etc/test/` because there are many files which will be copied into this folder over time and I don't want to run chmod command every time a file is copied over.

Comment: What `setfacl` command did you try? What was its output?

Comment: setfacl -Rm d:u::rwx,d:g::r,d:o::r /etc/test. There was no output it just accepted the command.

Comment: How are you copying the file? What happens if you use `/bin/cp` with no options?

Comment: The command I use is sudo cp /home/file /etc/test/file. I tried using /bin/cp now too with no different result

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Permissions are generally not propagated by the directory that files are being copied into, rather new permissions are controlled by the user's `umask`. However when you copy a file from one location to another it's a bit of a special case where the user's `umask` is essentially ignored and the existing permissions on the file are preserved.  Understanding this concept is the key to getting what you want.

So to copy a file but "drop" its current permissions you can tell `cp` to "not preserve" using the `--no-preserve=all` switch.

#### Example

Say I have the following file like you.

```
$ mkdir -m 744 somedir

$ touch afile
$ chmod 400 afile 

$ ll
total 0
-r--------. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 14 15:20 afile
```

And as you've confirmed if we just blindly copy it using `cp` we get this:

```
$ cp afile somedir/
$ ls -l somedir/
total 0
-r--------. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 14 15:20 afile
```

Now let's repeat this but this time tell `cp` to "drop permissions":

```
$ rm -f somedir/afile 

$ cp --no-preserve=all afile somedir/

$ ls -l somedir/
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 14 15:21 afile
```

So the copied file now has its permissions set to 664, where did it get those?

```
$ umask
0002
```

If I changed my `umask` to something else we can repeat this test a 3rd time and see the effects that `umask` has on the un-preserved `cp`:

```
$ umask 037
$ rm somedir/afile 

$ cp --no-preserve=all afile somedir/
$ ls -l somedir/
total 0
-rw-r-----. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 14 15:29 afile
```

Notice the permissions are no longer 664, but are 640? That was dictated by the `umask`. It was telling any commands that create a file to disable the lower 5 bits in the permissions ... these guys: (`----wxrwx`).

Comment: The `--no-preserve` flag isn't standard, presumably a GNUism.

Comment: Correct, thanks I meant to say that in the A.

Comment: in the spirit of Valentine's Day I give you a virtual kiss , it works! THANKS!