# setting default permission for directory

Tags: linux, permissions

Before anyone tags this question as duplicate, I would like to emphasize that I
would like to know something extra...

I found a way to [set the default file permissions for all files created in a
directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)

If I apply this procedure to a directory `my_dir` all the files and
subdirectories that will be created inside `my_dir` will have the correct
permission. But if I create a file outside `my_dir` and then copy or move it
inside `my_dir`, it won't have the permission defined in `my_dir`.

So I'd like to know if there's a way to fix the permission of a directory and
its contents for all files that are inside that directory no matter where the
files have been created.

The best solution would be one where the user has nothing special to do. Simple click and drag, copy, `cp`, `mv`... but nothing to do with `chmod` or so. Therefore an answer like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/file-inheriting-permission-of-directory-it-is-copied-in) is not really what I'm looking for because the user will have to do something unusual anytime he wants to copy or move a file.

PS: the reason why I'd like to do that is because I share some folders with
colleagues who are in the same group as me. I want that anyone in that group
has the right to `wrx` any file contained in the shared folders even if the
files have been created outside the folder.

Comment: Check the ACL explanation on this http://superuser.com/questions/237802/how-to-set-default-permissions-for-files-moved-or-copied-to-a-directory

Comment: When you assign an ACL to a directory, all the objects copied /moved to that directory will inherit the permissions assigned. That's just the thing you need. Keep in mind that every possible solution will need `root`privileges to apply it.

Comment: @jcbermu, as far as I've tried the `setfacl` works well for files created in the directory but doesn't for files that are moved into it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the file permission groups for your users. Request from your admin to establish a new group in `/etc/groups`, add all the team users to that group. Change the `umask` definitions in the user's shell profile to allow the access for members of the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Write wrapper scripts for `cp`, `mv`, etc., that do the `chmod` after copying.

Comment: yeah, but some of my colleagues won't be happy to use the terminal for copy/move files. this is why I'd like to find a really really "user friendly" solution... but thanks

Answer (score 0):

If ACLs won't cut it then the fallback solution is to use the `inotify` API. This allows a program to watch for events within one or more directories and act on them.

Something like this, wrapped up in a script that's started as root at boot time, will get you on your way:

```
TARGET_DIR='/path/to/directory'
inotifywait --monitor --recursive --quiet --event close_write,moved_to --format '%w/%f' "$TARGET_DIR" |
    while read FILE
    do
        chmod go=u,o-w "$FILE"
        # chown someone:somegroup "$FILE"
        logger -t inotify "Tickled $FILE"
    done
```